# XMPPError:forbidden auth error while creating new user using smack 4.1.2

Tags: ejabberd, smack

I am trying to create user using smack client 4.1.2. I am getting below error.

```
Send XML on stream = <<"<iq from='abc.example.com' to='admin@abc.example.com/Smack' id='Dym8b-14' type='error'><query xmlns=jabber:iq:register><password>xxxxxx</password><username>user</username><registered/></query><error code=403 type=auth><forbidden xmlns=urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas/></error></iq>">>
```

My ejabberd config looks like below (.yml file)

```
register_from:
admin: allow
...
access_from: register_from
access: register
```

I am still getting above error. Please help

Adding code snippet to show how I create new user using smack 4.1.0

```
connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(getConnectionConfiguration());
                connection.connect();
                connection.login("admin", "admin");
                if(connection.isAuthenticated())
                {
                    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(connection);
                    accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
                    accountManager.createAccount(userName, password);
                    connection.disconnect();
                    // The account has been created, so we can now login
                    connection.login(userName, password);
                }

private XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration getConnectionConfiguration()
{

    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
              .setServiceName("abc.example.com")
               .setHost("abc.example.com")
               .setPort(5222)
              .build(); 

    return config;
}
```

Comment: It seems the indentation of you configuration file is Incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the issue. It was due to trusted_network tag had value as loopback:allow in ejabberd config file. I changed it to all:allow. It started working.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet of configuration you provide is too small and badly indented, so it is impossible to tell you what is wrong in your configuration.

However, considering your config is correct, you should check that your user is properly authenticated with the right ACL credentials before sending the register request. Most client libraries assume self user registration and try to send the register before doing any form of authentication.

Comment: Hi Remond, apologies for late response. I checked yml file using yamlLint and its successfully parsed. So no issue with formatting. How can I check user is authenticated with right ACL credential before sending register request.

Comment: Hi Remond, I have added a code snippet where I try to create user. please let me know if this gives you any hint about issue

Comment: can this be an issue? its in my config yml file. `  ## Only allow to register from localhost
  trusted_network: 
    loopback: allow  
    ##
    ## Only clients in the server machine can register accounts
    ##
    ip_access: trusted_network' If so, what should I change value to?